# On EC2: sudo node command not found, but node without sudo is ok

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-ec2, sudo

I have just installed nodejs on a new EC2 micro instance.

I installed it normally, ./configure -> make -> sudo make install.

**Problem:** When I run "node" under ec2-user, it runs perfectly. When I run "sudo node", it fails.

I found out that node is in:

```
[ec2-user@XXXX ~]$ whereis node
node: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node
```

and the current path is

```
[ec2-user@XXXX ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

but, the sudo path is

```
[root@ip-10-112-222-32 ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin
```

then I tried to edit the root PATH to include the paths to node, so "node" runs when I'm logged in as root - but it still won't work when I log in as ec2-user and run "sudo node".

I need this to install npm properfly. Any idea on how to include the node path while running "sudo node"?

Comment: How did you edit the root PATH?

Comment: After much trying, I did this and it works: <pre>
sudo su export PATH=$PATH:usr/local/node/ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
</pre>

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Yes, it is a bit annoying but you can fix it with some links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node-waf /usr/bin/node-waf
```

There might be more but that is all I have run across so far. Lack of node-waf will cause some `npm` installs to fail with a rather cryptic error message.

Comment: I am just curious, does this linking has to be done only in Amazon AMI system? Does Amazon AMI system separate root path from user path?

Comment: Lack of `node-waf` causes `npm rebuild` to error out. Is there a clean way to remedy this? Do I need to?

Comment: This didn't work for me for a couple reasons.  1) I don't have sudo access.  I'm on a shared host.  2) `/usr/local` doesn't exist.  I made a directory ~/local, though.  3) After removing `/usr` and `sudo` from each of these lines of code and running them through my console, nothing had changed.

Comment: That was helpfull. But can anybody expalin why and how it gets things working ?

Comment: @Tarun: read up on the shell's PATH variable and how it is used to find which binary to execute for any given command. The ln command just links a second name to the same file.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDillon. "ln" means giving a another link for the a path. right?

Comment: Helped me with similar issue with composer on an EC" instance. Installed globally `composer self-update` gave permissions error  `[ErrorException]
  rename(/home/ec2-user/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied`    BUT sudo composer self-update couldn't find composer. Adding link as suggested worked a treat.

Comment: I'm using Amazon Linux. Is the line 'sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node' meant to be 'sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/lib/node_modules'?

Comment: `sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/bin/node` if you're afraid of typos and you use nvm like me. I also added the `sudo ln -s /path/to/lib/node_modules /usr/lib/node_modules` and `sudo ln -s $(which npx) /usr/bin/npx` symlinks to be safe.

Answer (score 39):

it happens because the node executable is not found in /usr/bin. So follow the steps:

1. find node:

`whereis node`

in my case: `node: /home/<my_user>/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node`

2. make a symbolic link for node:

   `sudo ln -s /home/<my_user>/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node /usr/bin/node`

It's done!

Comment: great tip - I also did `sudo ln -s  /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm` as I was trying to do sudo `npm install` on my aws ec2 instance after following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html)

Comment: You are a lifesaver and an absolute legend. +1

Answer (score 35):

I added `/usr/local/bin` to `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Then change this line:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

To:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 14):

Why not use the absolute path to node? If you planning to use an upstart script it is going to need an absolute path anyways.

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/node server.js
```

Comment: best solution, works and doesn't mess with the system like all `ln` solutions do.

Answer (score 6):

try the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
sudo node --version
```

Comment: Won't work for distributions which has `secure_path` set in `sudoers` file.

Answer (score 6):

You could pass full path to `node` executable from parent (non-sudo shell) using `which` command.

```
sudo `which node`
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using "sudo $(which node)" instead of "sudo node" ?

Answer (score 4):

For me, it worked to just change ownership of node folder from root to ec2-user (logged in as ec2-user).

(Note: I created my node folder in /var/lib/)

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/lib/node/
```

Then

```
npm install mongojs
```

should work fine (provided you have installed npm ok of course!)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that doesn't use symlinks, or require root:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
$ cd node
$ mkdir ~/opt
$ export PREFIX=~/opt; ./configure
$ make
$ make install
$ echo 'export PATH=~/opt/bin:${PATH}' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then I did:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
$ cd npm
$ make install
```

The benefits of not running node as root are discussed here:

http://increaseyourgeek.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/install-node-js-without-using-sudo/

Its inline with:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Node was installed without **sudo** prefix. So node was unavailable for the superuser that why it is not working `sudo node server`

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed node environment already, paste these command in you r instance and it'll link your node to your user directory. And you will be able to use node with sudo.

```bash
    sudo ln -s "$(which node)" "/usr/local/bin/node"
    sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter as root with

```
sudo su
```

and then do [standard steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install node
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve a similar issue. Note: I had installed node via snap.

Step 1: Install node via snap

```
sudo snap install node --classic
```

Step 2: Find where node has been installed

```
whereis node
```

In my case

```
/snap/bin/node.npm 
/snap/bin/node.npx 
/snap/bin/node.yarn 
/snap/bin/node 
/snap/bin/node.yarnpkg
```

Step 3: Create symbolic links to node, npm, npx and yarn

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/yarn /usr/bin/yarn
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Finally node is accessible for all users, even sudo group

```
sudo node
```

[image: Installing node via snap for all users, ubuntu, debian]

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything mentioned in the above answers but nothing worked. Probably because of my lack of understanding of concepts related to sym links. I fixed the issue by not using nvm.
I just created a new ec2 instance and didn't install nvm. Instead I installed node and npm like so:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

And this did it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the right way, but this is what i did...

```
sudo su
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ec2-user/local/node/bin
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
chown -R ec2-user /home/ec2-user/local/node
exit
```

This installed npm, and I can now install any packages I want.