# sudo has different environments, why?

Tags: bash, root, sudo, env

I realize that:

```
sudo -i
env
```

is different from:

```
sudo -i
sudo env
```

They are both sudo, why are they different?

In my case, I realize the PATHs are very different, so sometimes things can't run with "sudo blah" but it works when I first log into sudo, then run the command. (Like my other question [#4976658](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are expected differences, such as `SUDO_USER`, `SUDO_UID`, and `SUDO_GID`.

And then there is `PATH`.

When you run

```
sudo -i
env
```

you should expect root's `PATH`, but when you run

```
sudo -i
sudo env
```

you should expect a default `PATH`.

I think you will find that this is due to the "secure path" option, that both Ubuntu and Fedora have adopted.

I agree it's annoying.  There are many other threads about this behavior. :-/

For example, see this stackoverflow thread:
[sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)