# How to install Titanium Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: titanium, ubuntu-12.04, appcelerator

Does anyone know how to install titanium studion on ubuntu (>= 12.04)?
I spend the whole day, and I always had the same problem. Titanium studio forced me to update and return an error :

```
Error encountered during update
Failed to install acs. Please see the Studio log for more information.


log : 
> acs@1.0.11 postinstall /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /usr/lib/node_modules/acs
 node scripts/config.js


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: 
/home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek:
/home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for grzesiek: /usr/lib/node_modules/acs/scripts/config.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
npm ERR! acs@1.0.11 postinstall: `node scripts/config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the acs@1.0.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the acs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/config.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls acs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-39-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "acs" "--color" "false"
npm ERR! cwd /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/grzesiek/Titanium_Studio/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.update.core 4 4 2014-01-16 19:46:03.615
!MESSAGE Error encountered during update
!SUBENTRY 1 com.aptana.js.core 4 0 2014-01-16 19:46:03.615
!MESSAGE Failed to install acs. Please see the Studio log for more information.
```

Comment: You might want to ask here; http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Check [This](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/139823/ubuntu-1204-problem-on-startup) thread and api docs for 
[Troubleshooting a Studio Install on Linux](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Troubleshooting_a_Studio_Install_on_Linux-section-30083014_TroubleshootingaStudioInstallonLinux-Ubuntu12.04/PrecisePangolinStartupIssues)

Comment: If I type `sudo npm -e install acs` I got a successfull install although I don't know the difference, but still `Titanium` can't install `acs`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405906/installing-titanium-acs

Comment: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Titanium+Minimum+System+Requirements It says max version 11.10 :(

Comment: Random Guess: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue here, for some reason Titanium SDK doesn't work with the latest version of Ubuntu :( I solved by downgrading my Ubuntu since my development is mainly based in Titanium but I can imagine that this is not the right solution for everybody...

Comment: How did you downgraded? Is there a way other than formatting your HD and lose your data?

Comment: Thankfully I had my /home in a different partition so I managed to downgrade safely. Anyways, I think the ubuntu installer is capable of making an installation preserving all your relevant data (i.e. /home /usr/local /var/local ...)

Comment: You downgraded to which version?

Comment: 11.10 you can find the old releases here: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

Comment: I tried it on `Ubuntu 11.10` and didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked like lot of times in the internet and havent seen a solid answer or someone got this working. I had this problem for like 2 weeks and finally I managed to solve it. Meaning I have just installed Titanium 5.x on Ubuntu 15.10 successfully after like 2 weeks non-stop tedious attempts. I have seen this problem of Titanium forums and StackOverflow posts lot of times but again - NO SOLID ANSWER. I hope someone will be able to use this as a solution.

I cant guarantee the correctness of this solution but these are the steps I follow.

**Install JDK**

This has to be 7 or 8 according to the official documentation.

**Install Node.js**

For linux node.js version has to be between 0.1x and 4.2x. These are the supported version according to the documentation. The latest version of node is higher than this and there is no gurantee that it will work. So I also downgraded to 4.0.0 version.

**Download and install Titanium**

You will have to sign in first and download the titanium appcelerator setup zip file. Unzip it any where. Go in to that directory and execute as any user AppeceratorStudio file. This same user should have the ownership of .npm and .appcelerator directories. When you execute this file for the first time it just connects to appcelerator aws servers and downloads the configuration. We just cant see it . No indication what so ever. No indication in ps aux, top or netstat. So just brave your self untii this is over. This takes a looooooooooooooong time. So dont uninterrupt this. If all goes well, you have titanium.

**If uninterrupted ->**

You will have to simply to do the configration again. Luckily when you are using Titanium CLI also you can do the configuration.

// This downloads titanium CLI and configure it

sudo npm install appcelerator -g

appc setup

After this you can run AppeceratorStudio file and start working on Titanium.

This site was helpful.

http://kalpa-gunarathna.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-install-titanium-appcelerator-on.html

Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix: `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

**Reason:** If you check the contents of the folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, the folders within are owned by `nobody:staff` regardless of what user you did the npm install with, even with root or sudo. Fixing the permissions of this folder allowed acs to install with no further event.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Appcelerator Studio on Ubuntu.

1. Oracle's Java Development Kit (JDK) is required to be installed in order to work with Titanium. "Be aware that no other flavors of JDK, such as OpenJDK, currently work with Titanium; only Oracle's will suffice." To install the Oracle JDK, enable the archive repositories and install the package using the apt-get command. If installing the 64-bit JDK, run sudo apt-get install ia32-libs. Complete guide in here http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Oracle_JDK
2. On Mac OS X and Windows, if you have selected to install Titanium updates, Studio prompts you to install Node.js. On Linux, you need to manually install Node.js. Complete guide in http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Node.
3. Download Appcelerator studio and Install it.
4. TO Get Started with the CLI. Ensure that you have Node.JS, npm, java installed.

"java -version"
"node -v"
"npm -v"

Now Install the Appcelerator CLI:

"sudo npm install appcelerator -g"

After installation, you need to run setup to kick things off:

"appc setup"

Now start working on Appcelerator.