# Installing npm on ec2 returns 127 error

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm

I am trying to install npm on the amazon ec2 instance.

I already installed git and node.js in my instance

What I typed was these

```
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.10.20
./configure
make
sudo make install
git clone https://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```

But will end up with this error

```
rm -rf \
    .building_ronn \
    html/doc \
    html/api \
    man
scripts/doc-build.sh doc/api/npm-test.md man/man3/npm-test.3
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/npm'
node cli.js install ronn --no-global
bash: node: command not found
make[1]: *** [node_modules/.bin/ronn] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/npm'
make: *** [man/man3/npm-test.3] Error 2
```

Comment: why are you installing npm? It is bundled with node.js

Comment: Also, if you use `&&` between configure, make, and make install, you can be certain that one will complete successfully before the next process starts. It appears that either building Node.js was unsuccessful, or its install location is not on your $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

This question's progression of commands are in reference to [How to install & setup Node.js on Amazon EC2](http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/)
  which was written in 2012 and doesn't acknowledge that `npm` now comes bundled with node.js. You can type `which npm` to see that it's already installed and then safely `rm -rf npm/` the vestigial `npm` folder.

(If using `sudo npm` results in `command not found`, you may need to set up symlinks like so: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok/5062718#5062718](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5062718/2046886))