# sudo npm command not found (node installed from NVM)

Tags: node.js, npm, sudo, nvm

I just install node.js 4.4.4 from NVM on ubuntu 14.04.

`npm --version` give me `2.15.1`

`sudo npm --version` give me `sudo: npm: command not found`

I first tried to solved my problem with [that Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok) but as I installed node with NVM then node is install into ~/.nvm/ instead of the default location ...

**Note** `whereis npm` give me `npm:` with nothing after

EDIT

I've just read that NVM should remove `sudo` requirement in node process. But when I try `npm install pm2 -g` I receive `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` which doesn't make sens ...

Comment: Try `sudo -s` before running your npm commands.

Comment: I don t think its a good idea to install pm2 as root. I would not do that myself. see also http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/