# NPM does not recognize the command

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm

Previously it worked now NPM return

```
CMD:npm install any
Usage: npm <command>
where <command> is one of:
access, adduser, ...
```

Although if you do `npm -v` return `3.10.9`

Comment: What platform are you on? For *nix, try with and without sudo. If one of them works, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok/5062718#5062718 should help

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling npm?

Comment: @Qrchack I use Windows Os

Comment: @RyanZim it`s work!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: @RyanZim thx!))