# Centos 7 : node: command not found

Tags: node.js, centos7

I was installing node to my new Centos machine. I followed these steps as i needed node version 0.10

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/node-v0.10.33.tar.gz 
tar xzvf node-v* && cd node-v*
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
./configure
make
```

O/P of make command ended with

```
 LINK(target) /root/node-v0.10.33/out/Release/node: Finished
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/node-v0.10.33/out'
ln -fs out/Release/node node
```

Then i did

```
sudo make install
```

after that when i did `node --version` 
it says

```
bash: node: command not found
```

However

```
whereis node gives  me this

node: /usr/local/bin/node
```

Can someone please shed some light on it 
P.S: This is the link i followed for installation 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server

PPS: This is what my node-v dir look like after installation

```
AUTHORS    BSDmakefile  common.gypi  config.mk  CONTRIBUTING.md  doc  LICENSE   node      out        src   tools
benchmark  ChangeLog    config.gypi  configure  deps             lib  Makefile  node.gyp  README.md  test  vcbuild.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue .. Should have researched it first . Sorry 
Duplicate of 
[On EC2: sudo node command not found, but node without sudo is ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok)

Answer (score 0):

install node via yum

> yum update
>
> yum install epel-release
>
> yum install nodejs
>
> node --version

To access npm to manage their Node packages.

> yum install npm