# How to install node/npm so that 'sudo npm' works on an ec2 instance?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, amazon-ec2, nvm

Answer: Follow the steps in this link

http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/

I am running ubuntu on an ec2 instance and need to `sudo npm install` something. I am given the error that `sudo npm is not recognized`.

There is a previous thread that is 7 years old. [On EC2: sudo node command not found, but node without sudo is ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok?rq=1) I tried every solution there and nothing worked.

I think the problem is using NVM to install npm and node. How can I install these so that they are compatible with sudo? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using sudo to do this? Also is `apt install npm` not working? If you already have nvm installed what does it say when you try to install the latest stable npm version?

Comment: Installing the latest web3 module requires sudo npm install. I've terminated the instance that I was trying everything on to have a clean start; looking at the answer below I'm going to switch to RedHat. However, I did confirm that the latest npm was installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following command

> sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel

For more, you can also install using the following link also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

### Second Approach:

**Install NPM**

```
git clone https://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo env PATH=$HOME/local/node/bin:$PATH make install
```

Now you can install npm packages and run javascript node files as usual!

```
sudo npm install forever -g
sudo npm install express -g
```

Resource Link: http://www.wisdomofjim.com/blog/how-to-install-node-and-npm-on-an-ec2-server

Comment: First approach returns `Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found`

Second approach fails at sudo env PATH... with error message `make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.`

Thanks though, I will research these error messages

Comment: As I said above, the first and second approaches did not work. Installation through the resource link http://www.wisdomofjim.com/blog/how-to-install-node-and-npm-on-an-ec2-server did work. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if my problem is the same as yours (i think is similar), but i tried to run "sudo npm install" on a amazon linux ec2 machine and it gave me the "sudo: npm: command not found" type of problem.

I followed the instructions recommended by AWS to install node and NPM (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html).

I solve this by changing the owner and group of the directory and files (package.json and package-lock.json):
`chown ec2-user:ec2-user nameDir`

and then i run `npm install` again. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use NVM. You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c) link which gives proper steps to install node on ec2 instance.

Comment: Using NVM (at least the way I was doing it) does not easily allow for `sudo npm` module installation. If someone needs this functionality, I would recommend the ec2 redhat instance and following the installation instructions in the link.