# /usr/bin/env node : not found while executing sudo node

Tags: node.js, npm, centos, sudo

I've a dedicated vps running on cent os. I installed node on that by using

```
yum install nodejs
```

It installed successfully without any error and it shows version also.

```
node -v
v10.16.0
```

But it shows an error while running this with sudo

```
sudo node
Command not found
```

And when I try to run npm with sudo it shows

```
sudo npm
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I tried many solutions from here like

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

and many more.
I've also tried reinstalling node but still no luck.

Comment: Here's another post with the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5062718/4054878). The accepted answer however is a workaround.

Comment: @NtokozoZwane I've already tried that solution but still no luck.

Comment: sudo does not preserve your $PATH environment variable for security reasons. The command you want to run (node or npm) in your own user's shell using process substitution with which.
sudo "$(which npm)" install express or
sudo "$(which node)" bin/www